# Is there a way to safely hide HTML tags in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm recently starting to explore AngularJS, and of course, i know it is ran at the client side, and since SPA (Single Page Applications) are becoming more and more common, i have a question regarding how to safely hide HTML elements.

Let me give a simple example:

```
Employee
<div ng-show="canSeeSalary">
    {{salary}}
</div>
```

Now, of course, at runtime the div tag related to the salary won't be displayed, however by seeing the HTML source code, or using a developer tool like the one we have in Chrome, it would be possible to see the tag and probably its value.

I know tags like these should be filtered at the the server-side, of course, but since it has come to the client side, the div will be there.

My question is exactly, if there is any way i could hide these divs from the HTML source code, without needing to mix AngularJS with JSTL, for example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The server should *never* send data that you do not want the user to see. End of story.

Comment: @Mooseman This. They're going to get suggestions to use ng-if, but that won't solve the problem. Just don't send it in the first place, it's the only way.

Comment: @Mooseman, I agree, but supposing it isn't a so 'critical' information (of course in my example, salary IS a critical information - suppose its another one then, like the Dog's name), the user might find a way to see it, but i want to turn things a little more difficult.

Comment: @BrunoBL If you don't mind the possibility that users may see it, then yes, `ng-if` is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [**ng-if**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive:

```
<div ng-if="canSeeSalary">
    {{salary}}
</div>
```

Corresponding div element will be removed from the DOM. From the official documentation:

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates
>   to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a
>   clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

Comment: ng-if doesn't do what i expected. In tests, i was still able to see the content inside the div, by looking at the source code of the page.. with  the expression false or not.

Comment: @BrunoBL, are you sure? See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mdemidas/qyrakd4j/1/) demo. As you can see using Chrome inspector an element protected by ng-if disappears completely from the DOM.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks for the example, by using Element Inspector yes, it is somewhat protected.. Now right click on the frame/page -> "View Frame Source Code" and we can see the text "This is removed when the checkbox is unchecked.", and this is what i was actually trying to hide..from the page source code.

Comment: @BrunoBL, you can try to load controllers / views dynamically (see [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs) for example). Maybe you will be able to prepare two different pairs controller + view, then load them according to the user rights. I didn't tried this approach. For me it looks like a lot of work. And even if some public user will see some part of protected template, I don't understand how he could use this information? Do you know some case where it may be dangerous?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Employee
<div ng-if="canSeeSalary">
    {{salary}}
</div>
```

**ng-if** completely removes and recreates the element in the DOM rather than changing its visibility via the display css property

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using ngCloak rather than ngIf.

The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

example:

```
<div ng-cloak> {{::test}} </div>
```

[ngCloak @ Official Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)